# Unable to validate form in codeigniter. After submitting form serverside validation is not happening if form is empty null values are inserting db

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

After submitting the view page, if the form fields don't contain values then error messages should appear, but in my case, null values are inserted in the database. So please help me where I am going wrong.

If form fields are empty then, if condition should be executed and then view page should be shown with error messages, instead of executing if condition its executing  other code and inserting null values in data base.
Controller

```
public function test_submit()
{
    
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('test_name', 'Test Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[add_test.TestName]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('test_price', 'Test Price', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('correct_answer', 'Corrent Answer', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('wrong_answer', 'Wrong Answer', 'trim|required');
        
     if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
     {

        $this->load->view('add_test_view');

     }
        
    $test_name=$this->input->post('test_name');
    $description=$this->input->post('description');
    $test_price=$this->input->post('test_price');
    $correct_answer=$this->input->post('correct_answer');
    $wrong_answer=$this->input->post('wrong_answer');
    
        
    $insert_data = array(
        'TestName' =>$test_name,
        'Description' => $description,
        'Price' => $test_price,
        'CorrectAnswerMarks' => $correct_answer,
        'WrongAnswerDeduction' => $wrong_answer
        
            
    );
        
    $result=$this->test_model->add_test($insert_data);
    
    $this->session->set_tempdata('success', "Test with name ".$test_name." Is Added Successfully.","20");
    redirect('testmodule/addtest', 'refresh');  
    
     }
```

Comment: You really dont need a model to insert data. When you run your IF(validation...), insert your data as an else statement. Either show your test page or insert the data. Make your $this->input->POST data an array and insert that. Like this $this->db->insert("table name", $array of post data);

Comment: Welcome to SO.  "*is not working*" does not tell us anything. What happens?  Are you seeing errors?  Which field failed validation?  Is your form rendered correctly?  You've shown us a bunch of PHP code for generating a form - does it work? What does the *rendered* HTML form look like? Is your form really POSTing? Have you checked your browser's devtools, and looked at the network request - is it a POST, are all the values you expect really being sent?  This question is likely to be closed unless you edit it and give us some more info.

Comment: it would tremendously help us to help you, if you could describe what is not working, specifically pointing out any error codes as well as to describe the code's behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should insert the data in else part of the validation like below:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
{
 $this->load->view('add_test_view');
} else {
 // Insert code should go here
}
```

This will ensure data insertion only when validation is succefull.
You should make use of the validation_error() function to display the error message like below:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
 $this->session->set_flashdata("error", validation_errors());
 redirect('your_controller/your_function');
}
```

In the above all the errors due to which validtion failed will be displayed on the view. Using redirect also ensures the execution of that function stops there . You have to use below in you view:

```
<div class="text-danger text-center text-bold"><b><?=$this->session->flashdata('error');?></b></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. please help me with this set_flashdata as well. Previously I used  set_flashdata, when  I am sending a flashdata error message when a form is filled incorrectly. The message is appearing correctly but does not clear on refresh/redirect. So switched to set_tempdata. Now I am using Codeigniter 3.1.11